# Datatables: Adding an extra row

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using ajax to load the Datatables faster, and I am not sure how to add an extra row... For example I would like the data to look like this:

```
=======================
first name || last name
=======================
name----- -||---last name
====================================
more info here and here
====================================
name2----- -||---last name2
====================================
more info here and here
====================================
```

The problem is that I am using ajax, so the table from the frontend just looks like:

```
<tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>loading...</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
```

How can I create additional rows when using Datatables ajax options? Any ideas? The code for ajax that I am using is the following: http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fnOpen method ... here are the details -> http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html

Comment: Link-only answers are low-value on Stackoverflow.  This network doesn't seek to be a traffic re-director -- rather, the idea is for all of the necessary advice to be hard-coded here so that there is never 100% reliance on an external resource.  Please be more generous with your answer and edit it to include how to implement your advice as well as explain how it works and why you feel it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can add rows using [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Link-only answers are low-value on Stackoverflow.  This network doesn't seek to be a traffic re-director -- rather, the idea is for all of the necessary advice to be hard-coded here so that there is never 100% reliance on an external resource.  Please be more generous with your answer and edit it to include how to implement your advice as well as explain how it works and why you feel it is a good idea.